# Mapping MySQL Double to PHP Float with Doctrine's ORM

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm attempting to implement Doctrine's ORM into my micro-framework as I've heard many good things about it, however, I'm finding the documentation somewhat lacking.

I am implementing the ORM on a project with an existing MySQL database, and in it, they used Double as the column type. My inquiry lies with mapping the MySQL double to the PHP float in regards to precision and scale.

The Doctrine ORM documentation states that the default precision and scale values are 0. However, the MySQL documentation states that precision and scale should not be used with float and double:

> Because floating-point values are approximate and not stored as exact values, attempts to treat them as exact in comparisons may lead to problems. They are also subject to platform or implementation dependencies. For more information, see Section B.3.4.8, “Problems with Floating-Point Values”
>
> For maximum portability, code requiring storage of approximate numeric data values should use FLOAT or DOUBLE PRECISION with no specification of precision or number of digits.
>
> -> [Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html)

Here is the snippet from the Doctrine ORM documentation:

> - precision (default: 0): The precision for a decimal (exact numeric) column (applies only for decimal column), which is the maximum number of digits that are stored for the values.
> - scale (default: 0): The scale for a decimal (exact numeric) column (applies only for decimal column), which represents the number of digits to the right of the decimal point and must not be greater than precision.
>
> -> [Source](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.11/reference/basic-mapping.html#basic-mapping)

So, does anyone with experience using Doctrine's ORM know if not specifying the precision and scale values in the mapping will cause issues? From my understanding, Doctrine's ORM is going to try and treat these values as exact numeric values and I can see 0 either being used as the numeric equivalent of null (not MySQL null, but as in, if 0 ignore it) and the ORM just mapping the values as-is **or** the ORM quite literally not mapping any value because the precision by default specifies 0 allowed digits (both perspectives seem valid to me).

**Do Note:** I haven't actually tried anything yet as I'm still in the process of updating my entity models and configuring the ORM. My question so far stems from an interest in learning more about this and hearing from those with experience as I've not found any reference to this matter in the documentation or elsewhere.

Comment: what about casting mysql as DECIMAL and using the result.

Comment: That's a good idea. Right now, any alterations to the DB are out of the scope of my work, however, we do plan to refactor the DB later this year. This is one such refactoring - using the correct types. Trust me, the db needs a lot of refactoring. All ints are saved as MySQL strings and they're using MySQL bit instead of just using a bool.

Comment: no i meant `SELECT CAST(yourvalue AS DECIMAL(12,2))` so you have the precison you need